# Override Ext.data.Store, call constructor

Tags: javascript, extjs, overriding

I want to override Ext.data.Store so that all stores have custom exception handling.

So I coded:

```
Ext.define("Override.data.Store", {
    override:'Ext.data.Store',
    constructor:function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if(this.getProxy() && this.getProxy().getReader())
        this.getProxy().getReader().on('exception',function(reader,response,error) {
            if(!isLoggedIn(response)) window.location.reload();
            else Ext.Msg.alert("Error reading data.",error);
        });
    }
});
```

I think that instead of `this.callParent(arguments);` I would have to use some other hokey-pokey function, because I don't want the constructor of the superclass of Store, but the constructor of the original Store. Does anyone know how to take a function from the overridden class?

Second, to get it working, into which directory will I have to put that override definition? The original Store is in `ext/data/Store.js`, I did put my file into `app/override/data/Store.js`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [callSuper](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-callSuper) that should do what you want.